# EF 6, update model from database does not support object context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

We have a fairly elaborate data model built from an existing database, then enhanced using partial classes to support additional methods & properties, inheritance, etc.  We have not yet bitten the bullet to update this from ObjectContext to DbContext.

I am using VS2012, .net 4.5, EF 6.0.2, and have installed the EF 6.0.2 Tools for VS2012.

Following the recommended mechanism to update a project to EF6 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469466) has been successful, including the addition of the EF 6 Entity Object generator as the code generation item.

Subsequent to making this change, I would like to update the model from the database to incorporate some recent schema changes into the model. Running through the "update model from database" dialog, what appears to be happening is that an entirely new dbcontext-based model & template is added to the project, in addition to the object context-based model that already exists in the project, and none of the changes are incorporated into the entity-object template.

Of course, this means there are hundreds of duplicate names defined in the project once the operation completes.  The edmx properties do not appear to have an option that would control this behavior.

Certainly, making the transition to dbcontext is the right avenue ultimately, but would like to avoid taking that on imminently.

Comment: is the code generation style set to T4 (which would make use of your Entity Object Generator)?

Comment: That is an interesting question.  Prior to executing "update model from database", as part of the preparation, I add the EF6 Entity Object code generation item to the model, remove the ".Designer.cs" file (which seemingly replicates (in EF5 mode) code generated by the new code generation item.  I can set the code generation style to Legacy ObjectContext as well, and the project builds as expected.

Comment: Once update model from database is executed, however, the dbcontext items are automatically added to the project, code generation style is changed to T4, and is grayed out.  So, it is an odd deal, indeed.

Comment: I also have this problem. I don't need to update my model from database YET, but this is certainly alarming and will make database updates very tedious.

Comment: Note that in the roadmap the ObjectContext will be dropped in EF7.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is open edmx file in visual studio by double-click and then select all tables perform a full delete(press del). Then click save button on top of menu bar, it should delete all models automatically.

After it's done, then you can update model from database again.

Hope this helps.